# Creating an measure to compare week-over-week developments

Tags: powerbi, dax

My dataset includes information from at 26 different weeks. It lists all the open items from an accounts receivable database for each of the 26 weeks. Each of the report dates is exactly 7 days apart.

I am trying to compare the current receivables with the amount of the last week.

I thought that I will just extract the last report date with

```
LastReport:=LASTDATE(Report Date)
```

which gave me indeed the last report date. I go back 7 days with

```
PriorWeek:=DATEADD(LastReport;-7;DAYS).
```

This worked fine.

However, when I try to calculate the sum of last week using

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Total AR);Reportdate=PriorWeek)
```

I can an error that I cannot compare date and text fields.

I have checked the report date column is set to date.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I would say 'No need of ranking the Dates'. My solution is below using calculated columns:

```
Amount Variance =
VAR _PrevBlank =
    ISBLANK ( [PrevWeek Amount] )
VAR _Amount = [Amount]
VAR _PrevAmount = [PrevWeek Amount]
VAR _Variance =
    IF ( _PrevBlank, 0, _Amount - _PrevAmount )
RETURN
    _Variance
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a date index using RANKX

```
RankDate = RANKX(Table1,Table1[Report Date],,ASC)
```

Then you can either create a calculated column that holds the previous week value

```
PreviousWeekCol = LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[Total AR],Table1[RankDate],Table1[RankDate]-1)
```

Or create a calculated measure that holds the prior week value

```
    PreviousWeekMeasure = 
    VAR MaxDateIndex = MAX(Table1[RankDate])
    RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Total AR]),Table1[RankDate]=MaxDateIndex-1)
```